# A Unique In-Order ID for each User

Tags: mysql

So I see other tutorials on how to create a unique id for each user, however i do not really want that. I would like an ID that is in order. For example, the first user will have an id of 00001. Second user 00002 and so on. I can't find any tutorials on this. I have a mysql database and can handle that, just need to know how to assign an in-order ID.

Comment: Just put the ID field in the table as `Auto increment`

Answer (score 0):

You could follow this syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE example(
   id int(6) zerofill not null auto_increment, 
   primary key(id)
);
```

Reference: [Numeric Type Attributes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-attributes.html)

Comment: Uh, I dont quite understand this. So are you creating the table everytime this gets run? How will i put this into a php variable?

Comment: It's just your MYSQL Table. You don't need to insert the id in the table at all. Every time a row is inserted, the id gets auto generated.

Comment: Alright, I have a INSERT TO statement to insert rows. Would i put this in the id section?

Comment: In your insert command, totally omit the id section. You could use the above command to create the table. Once table is created, the id will be auto generated when an INSERT query runs. No need to mention id in your query

Comment: Great Thanks! One past question. So right now i tried creating id for 3 people, then deleted some. It will now continue at 0004 instead of filling the id's i had before back in. How can I fix that?

Comment: Unfortunately, that can't be fixed when the field is `auto_increment`. However, if you truncate the entire table, it will start filling in the id's as 000001, 000002 ....